# How to update database with script

Tags: database, postgresql

I need to create Postgre DB in Windows. So I've downloaded the windows tools from the official site, created server and the problem appeared. When I try to create db in pgAdmin III I'm getting syntax errors while copying data. So I need to run the whole thing in the console. But pgAdmin only allows console mode for db already created and when I run it I have shell for my empty database:

dbname->

How can I now run my script ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In windows try this:

\i c:/somedir/script2.sql

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using psql.exe? Given psql.exe is on your path try:

`c:\> psql.exe -h localhost -U username -f c:\mysqlscript.sql database_name`